# In Blender Sculpting, how can I "repeat last stroke" like I can in Curve mode?

Tags: sculpting

When sculpting, after I draw a stroke with my brush, especially with Pinch or Crease, I would like to just duplicate the stroke to increase the strength/depth of the cut without having to manually go over the same line again.

I can't "repeat last" while I sculpt, as this takes me out of Sculpt mode and back to Object mode.

My only way I've found to repeat last stroke is to switch to the "curve" options (shotcut: E) which lets you select the stroke method: Curve.  Then I draw a curve (shortcut Ctrl + Right Click) and press enter to engage the stroke.  I can press enter multiple times to duplicate the stroke like I mentioned in first paragraph.  But I want to do this is plain, free-hand sculpting.

When I open an "info" window, the repeat operation with the enter key after curve does not appear, so I don't know what Blender is doing to allow it in curve mode.
If someone has a custom Python solution, I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pressing  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can hold  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>LMB</kbd> to realize the stroke multiple times.

[image]

You can also increase the strength of the stroke above 1.0, so that you do not have to realize the stroke multiple times.

**For Re-cycling the Curve**:
[image]

You can save your curve and reuse it in the future as many times as you want by clicking "Add New Paint Curve" shown on the screenshot above. And reuse it from the drop-down menu shown on the screenshot below.
[image]